# Json Deserialization of string "2023-11-10 23:01:18.940" to calendar

Tags: java, json, date, calendar

I am trying to deserialize json String date to Calendar and deserialization is working however it is not what i want.

*Current Behaviour*

```
@JsonProperty("systemDt")
@JsonFormat(Pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
Calendar responseDateTime;
```

Deserializes to `responseDateTime=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1141556400000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC".....`.

I want a Simple Calendar Date of the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Comment: Hey ... you shouldn't been using `Calendar` in new code.  It is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should been using `LocalDateTime` property in code.
eg:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(dateFormatter));
    }
```

output:

```
2023-11-30 10:59:47.852
```

final:

```java
@JsonProperty("systemDt")
@JsonFormat(Pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private LocalDateTime responseDateTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "2023-11-10 23:01:18.940"
    .replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
```

### Details

Not enough information. Your input represents a date and a time of day but lacks the context of an offset or time zone. So you cannot parse directly as a `Calendar`.

Also, `Calendar` is a terribly flawed obsolete legacy class.

Parse your input as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) after replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard.

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2023-11-10 23:01:18.940".replace( " " , "T" ) )
```

> I want a Simple Calendar Date of the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Date-time objects are not text. They do not have a format.